# How to get a Part of the URL?

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I have a link on my collection page on a Shopify store.

the link does look like this:

/collections/all?filter.p.tag=animal

I want to grab the current active Filters and print them again under the H1 Heading.

But I **HAVE TO** grab only everything after "tag="

So ignore the rest of the URL and also anything coming from things like "sort_by" or "?fbclid=IwAR2didTPblablabla"

So just everything after "tag="

How this can be done?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Comment: Please clarify the question.  The filter key could appear anywhere in a query string. Do you really want "everything after" which might include other keys? Or (more likely) do you want only the filter value?  Can there ever be more than one filter key in the url?  Are there any other keys used that also end in "tag=" ?

Comment: not directly meant "everything after", but all parameters tagged with "tag" in the url.

the path could also be /collections/all?filter.p.tag=animal&filter.p.tag=glitter

Answer (score 3):

Just to give a more fullfilling answer using URLSearchParams:

```js
const paramsString = "?filter.p.tag=animal";

const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);

console.log(searchParams.get('filter.p.tag'))
// result: animal
```

This will get the value from the `filter.p.tag` param eg `animal`.
Meaning if the url looks something like this:

```js
const paramsString = "?filter.p.tag=animal&sort_by=type";
```

it will still only return `animal`.

If you truly want "everything after "tag="", please see some of the other answers.

**Edit:** URLSearchParams' argument must be in the right format (eg.: `?some=thing`), so previously I answered it with:

```js
const paramsString = "/collections/all?filter.p.tag=animal";
...
```

which is incorrect. Only the actual search params string works in URLSearchParams.

To get the correct params string from the URL use `location.search`:

```js
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);

console.log(searchParams.get('filter.p.tag'))
```

Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: You should test your snippet because it is incorrect.  It returns null rather than "animal". And there is a reason it works that way.

Comment: @Yogi, you are right. Sorry about that. Fixing now.

Comment: but how i can output that lets say i have a class <span class="filteroutput">Here goes the active filters</span>

Comment: Well, grab the element with for example `const elm = querySelector(".filteroutput");` and insert the param with `elm.textContent = searchParams.get('filter.p.tag');`

Answer (score 0):

You could get the URL, parse it and keep the parts you care about.

Comment: Correct, but you'll also need to add some code and an explanation on how to do it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

window.location.href will give you the current URL in your web browser.

Then by using the split function with the argument "tag=" you split the string into 2 parts. You get an array back with the first value being the part up to tag=, and the second part is everything after tag=.

```
window.location.href.split("tag=")[1]
```

Comment: This would get everything after `tag=`, which while technically is what OP is asking for, they really are looking for [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Comment: That is not the question. I also don't see how the URL is built with multiple tags

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do it using JavaScript. Here are two options:

### Option 1, use the string split method

To get the search parameters of the URL, you can use something like `document.location.search`, which evaluates to everything after the "?" in the URL.

Then, you can split the string on "tag=" to get everything after "tag=".

Example code:

```js
const searchParams = document.location.search; // 'filter.p.tag=animal'
const splitString = searchParams.split('tag=');
const everythingAfterTag = splitString[1]; // 'animal'
```

### Option 2, use the URL object constructor

Here is a code example:

```js
const url = document.location.href; // get the entire URL string
const urlObject = new URL(url);
const valueOfTag = urlObject.searchParams.get('filter.p.tag'); // 'animal'
```

Comment: This is a good start, but the URL() constructor in your code will throw an error when given a relative url as in the example data.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const text="/collections/all?filter.p.tag=animal"
const n= text.indexOf("tag=")
const newtext= text.slice(n+4)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).